# primereact dialog not triggering onHide fn from footer actions for wrapper component

Tags: reactjs, dialog, wrapper, primereact

primereact dialog not triggering onHide fn from footer action for wrapper compoent

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-cdn-jkn5t?file=/src/demo/DialogDemo.js

isue: open console > open dialog > press no > console not print onhide (for esc and close btn working)

Answer (score 1):

Method `onHide` is not triggered when clicking these buttons.
It is only triggered when closing dialog from icon.

I altered your code and used `ref` in order to achive this via `props.onHide` call.
Check my
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-khorana-fqzb9?)